# How to change the colour of the seaborn boxplot extensive line and outliers?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

[image]

After changing the jupyter notebook theme color, I found it tricky to identify the plotting information like this one.... Is it possible to set the boxplot line and outlier dots to white so that I can see the outliers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the link below if you want to do one by one you can..use like this as dictionary--

```py
plt.boxplot(y1,
    boxprops = dict(linestyle='--', linewidth=3, color='darkgoldenrod'),       
    whiskerprops = dict(color='black', linewidth=5.0),
    capprops = dict(color='black', linewidth=5.0)
)
```

boxprops for box line and whiskerprops for whisker line,

https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html?highlight=whiskerprops

Comment: Thank you Lokesh, it solved the problem of the whiskerline, but do you have any thoughts of changing the color of outlier dots outsider the line?

Comment: showfliers=False or True will hide ad unhide outlier ..and color them use flierprops  refer below link...https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-boxplot-demo-pyplot-py